# Restoring Windows 7n Ultimate backup or system image to Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, restore, transfer, clean-install

I've been using Windows 7N via a key from a European friend for some time now, but have recently acquired a Windows 7 Ultimate (non-N) key:
I'd like to switch versions, partly for aesthetic reasons and partly because I've had impractically large issues with installing [Microsoft's Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16546).

Is there any way I can backup to a system image/backup from the N version, perform a clean install of the non-N version and restore to it?

Comment: Why don't you just the anytime upgrade system?  Be specific what do you want to transfer specifically from your old installation to your new installation?  Just personal files or installed Win32 programs?

Comment: Preferably all programs and data from my current install - how does the anytime upgrade system work? I've never heard of that

Comment: @Ramhound The [Anytime Upgrade System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Anytime_Upgrade) Doesn't really seem relevant, looks like it was discontinued and isn't for moving across windows 7 versions

Comment: While it was discontinued, have you verified, it still cannot be used to perform the upgrade anyways?  What your asking to do, is easily solved, with my suggestion.  While you can't buy keys anymore, you should still be able to, supply your own. Trust but verify

Comment: Also worth pointing out.  Feature Pack be not on the N versions are the only diff between non-N versions and N versions.  So perhaps we can solve the easier problem of getting the feature pack installed?

Comment: Anytime upgrade doesn't seem to let me transfer across here, though I think you're right about trying to troubleshoot the feature pack installation again - I made a post a while back to see what was happening with the standalone installer, but couldn't really find a fix, it may be worth asking again though I guess

Comment: Cheers for the help @Ramhound